# Trying to load .bashrc config file locally

Tags: cygwin

I'd like to create a `.bashrc` file in my Git Repo which should then be shared with other devs. The goals here is to add project-based aliases for every dev.

For instance when using node.js tools, a lot of them check the current directory for configuration files (ex: grunt looks for Gruntfile.js, JSHint looks for .jshintrc, npm for package.json).
I want Cygwin to look after `.bashrc` in the **local directory**.

I don't want to change the $HOME variable since it would allow me to only work on one project at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I fixed the issue with aliasas

1. Run `touch .bash_profile` command
2. change file to contain all aliases. Example:

#### file `.bash_profile`

```
alias ga='git add --all .'
alias gp='git push'
```

Every time you open the Bash, type `. .bash_profile` to reload the file and therefore register the aliases.